# Joining np.arrays Python with a padding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Analogous to:

```
"True".join(['False','False'])
```

I'd like to join numpy arrays, e.g.

```
arr = np.zeros((15,10), dtype=bool)
joiner = np.ones((15,1), dtype=bool)
result = np.hstack((arr, joiner, arr))
result.shape
(15, 21)
```

That is, I'd like to join a variable amount of arrays with a truth vector in between each of them.

```
arr, joiner, arr, joiner, arr, ...
```

How to extend the above for any number of arrays?

We can assume that they all have the same shape.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple quite silly appending method (I expect it to be really slow compared to some solutions out there):

```
def mergeArrays(*args):
    if args:
        joiner = np.ones((args[0].shape[0], 1))
        new = []
        for x in args[:-1]:
            new.append(x)
            new.append(joiner)
        new.append(args[-1])
        return np.hstack(new)
```